# Intellij Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use Intellij to make android apps instead of the Android studio. Problem is when I create a new `project`, I get the error

> "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly."
>   ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.

Fatal Error
Exception Report

> java.lang.AssertionError: Already disposed: Module: 'app'
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.lambda$throwAlreadyDisposed$1(ComponentManagerImpl.java:245)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.lambda$run$1(ReadAction.java:53)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:974)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:57)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.run(ReadAction.java:53)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.throwAlreadyDisposed(ComponentManagerImpl.java:243)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getPicoContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:236)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:146)
>       at com.intellij.facet.FacetManager.getInstance(FacetManager.java:31)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.facet.gradle.GradleFacet.getInstance(GradleFacet.java:57)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.getGradleBuildFile(GradleUtil.java:343)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssuesReporter.report(SyncIssuesReporter.java:89)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssuesReporter.report(SyncIssuesReporter.java:66)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.SyncIssueDataService.importData(SyncIssueDataService.java:40)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.doImportData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:298)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:165)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:251)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:258)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.wizard.GradleProjectImportBuilder$1.lambda$onSuccess$1(GradleProjectImportBuilder.java:144)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.wizard.GradleProjectImportBuilder$1.onSuccess(GradleProjectImportBuilder.java:154)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.ExternalProjectRefreshCallback.onSuccess(ExternalProjectRefreshCallback.java:40)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:574)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.lambda$execute$0(ExternalSystemUtil.java:399)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:146)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:399)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:664)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:731)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:586)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:86)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:311)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I've looked around on Google for a while, but I have not found a solution, I tried other solutions for other similar problems, but still nothing.

Comment: Just simply use android studio much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the appCompat version to:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
```

Instead

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+
```

Since the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX, no more appCompat at version 29.
You can also migrate to AndroidX (details here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat)

```
dependencies {
def appcompat_version = "1.1.0"

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
// For loading and tinting drawables on older versions of the platform
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"
}
```